# Alter views search api solr result

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am using search api and Solr, When I echo the result variable , it gave me the following results

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entity] => 442415
    [_entity_properties] => Array
    (
    [search_api_relevance] => 1
    [search_api_excerpt] =>
    [search_api_item_id] => 442415
    )

)
```

In views i added ( custom text field, that is global variable), With this nid 442415, i will do certain node load operation and finally,
i will get price for the specific product. This code block will execute inside the foreach.
_views_pre_render

Please guideme,

which hook i should use ,  _views_post_execute or _views_pre_render ?
How to assign new value in to which variable and how to print that in tpl

Finally, i want to display the price on each item

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2098575) resolved my problem.

**Solution approach**

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if($view->name == 'my_view') {
    foreach($view->result as &$row) {
        $row->_entity_properties['nothing'] = 'new value';
    }
  }
}
```

**views-view-field--view-name--display-name--nothing.tpl.php**

```
 print $row->_entity_properties['nothing'];
```